# Vertical scrollbar pushing content over, creating horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, overflow

So here's the page I'm working with right now: http://home-dev.mpcleague.com/contact

I'm working on positioning that right image so that it looks like it's coming out of the right side of your screen. So far looks good.

But I notice that when I plug my mouse in, Safari and/or Mac detects I have a mouse and displays a vertical scrollbar. That's normal, except for the fact that a little bit of the image (the width of the scrollbar) is now displaying off the edge of the screen, which creates a horizontal scroll bar.

The HTML/CSS relating to my image and its container is as follows:

```
<div class="col-md-6 image-col">
     <div class="image-container">
          <img class="contact-graphic" src="/assets/contact-us-graphic.png" />
     </div>

</div>

.image-container {
    height:70vh;
}
img.contact-graphic {
    height:100%;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.image-col {
    padding-right:0 !important;
    padding-left:0;
    margin-right:0 !important;
    overflow-x:hidden !important;
    width:50vw !important;
    margin-right:-50vw!important;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

On a sidenote, I get the feeling this css may not be the best. If you have any suggestions, I'd love the help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `width: 50vw!important;` from `.image-col`! It's part of the bootstrap grid.